# How do you change a logo to monochrome in Photoshop CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, monochrome

On many websites I see a list Customers they have and their logos where they have all been changed to some kind of grayscale.

*Logos example*
[image: Logos example]

*More logos with different background*
[image: More logos]

I understand it's not simply changing `Image > Mode > Grayscale`

Any tutorials, action scripts that I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the monochrome logo was not provided by the customer themselves, it was most probably made using a `Gradient Map`. A way to achieve the desired effect would be:

1. Open your logo file in Photoshop. Ideally, this is a file with transparency, but one with a (white) background will work as well.
2. Open the `Layers` palette: `Window > Layers` or <kbd>F7</kbd>.
3. Click the `Create new fill or adjustment layer` icon on the bottom of the panel. It's the circular icon, half black, half white.
4. Choose `Gradient Map`.
5. The `Properties` panel will pop up with a gradient. Edit the gradient to be from white to white (if you have a file with transparency) or from white to your desired background colour (if you have a white-background file).
6. Save as any desired format.

If you are discontent, you can tweak the gradient. Additionally, you can pop other layers with different logos into this file, and tuck them under the adjustment layer. THis way, all your logos will have the same gradient, without you having to reproduce it over and over.